# Can I use the maven ant tasks with a custom maven repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, build

I need to specify a certain directory which the maven ant tasks should use as repository.  **maven.repo.local** doesn't seem to work with that. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you post the paths around <artifact:localRepository id="local.repository" path="${maven.repo.local}"/> that aren't working?

Comment: I think I have to clarify my question :-)
localRepository does work indeed, my actual problem is to pass the parameters from maven to ant.

Answer (score 1):

you should look into the maven repositories tags.  You can specify a repository, but on a more global scale than you might like.

[maven repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)